# Resource allocation algorithm for an airlock on a moon base

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find an algorithm or problem name on a resource allocation problem that goes something like this.

A moon base has an airlock that only one person can use at a time, either to enter or exit, and takes 20 seconds to pass through. Airlock transitions cannot be aborted early or reversed. Astronauts have a limited amount of air when they are outside the base (say 10 minutes). Their job on the moon is to operate a number of drills that are different distances from the moon base, and keep them running with 100% manned uptime.

I hope to answer questions like these:
How many drill sites can be supported with no astronauts running out of air? How do you determine the schedule for the airlock (who gets to enter/exit and in what order)?

There are 2 components:
- First figuring out the number of astronauts required to man each drill site with 100% up time.
- Figuring out the number of drills that can be operated using one airlock

```
Per Drill:
MaxWorkTime[i] = AirTime - 2*TravelTime[i]
ActualWorkTime[i] < MaxWorkTime[i]
WorkersPerDrill[i] = AirTime/ActualWorkTime[i]

for each drill
  try to schedule airlock time
```

WorkTime can be reduced to schedule workers more optimally on the airlock as it approaches 100% utilization (I think).

Below is a simple diagram to try to clarify the problem more.  The airlock time is consumed by astronauts using it and is indicated by the bars. I want to increase usage to its maximum while not sending too many astronauts outside. The astronauts work cycle is shown for one drill. The astronaut uses airlock time to exit, walks to the worksite, works, walks back to base, and uses airlock to enter.

```
           |---time-->  

Airlock:   |--x---|               |--x---|              |--x---|             |--x---|

Astronaut1 |-lock-|--to--|---------drill1--------|-from-|-lock-|
Astronaut2                        |-lock-|--to--|-------drill1--------|-from-|-lock-|
                                                ^
                                         drill1 always manned
```

### Update (Example with numbers)

```
AirTime = 10min
WalkSpeed = 1 m/s


drill[0] = 180m     // 6min to/from travel
drill[1] = 150m     // 5min
drill[2] = 120m     // 4min
drill[3] = 240m     // 8min 

TravelTime[0] = 6min
...
MaxWorkTime[0] = AirTime - TravelTime[0] = 4min
...

// WorkersPerDrill = AirTime/MaxWorkTime
WorkersPerDrill[0] >= 2.5    // These numbers are over 1 airtime (10m)
WorkersPerDrill[1] >= 2
WorkersPerDrill[2] >= 1.67
WorkersPerDrill[3] >= 5

TotalWorkersPerAirtime = sum(WorkersPerDrill) = 11.17

AirlockTime = 20s
AirlockPerWorker = 40s
TotalAirlockUsage = TotalWorkersPerAirtime*AirlockPerWorker = 7.4 min of airlock time
                                                              74% usage of airlock if no one uses it at the same time
```

This is the first part of the problem. Once there is a conflict where drill[1] worker and drill[3] worker come back at the same time there is a chance one runs out of air.  That is the problem I'm trying to solve.  Thanks for putting up with this long winded question!

Comment: Could you make sure your code is properly formatted? Also, is this a homework?

Comment: It isn't homework. I don't need a solution, just a name of a problem/algorithm that I can start researching to understand it more. Does the diagram make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

This is not even a programming problem. More like just maths.

To have a single drill keep operating all the time, you need to at least spend 20+20 seconds every 10 minutes. That is for one guy to go back and one guy to come out.

You can change shifts more frequently, but that's always less efficient.

So, you need 40s door time per 10 minutes for a drill.

Then you can cascade the shift changing of each drill so they don't overlap as shown in diagram below:

```
        <-  10 mins  -> 
drill-1  x--------------x--------------x--------------x
drill-2  -x--------------x--------------x--------------
drill-3  --x--------------x--------------x-------------
...
drill-15 --------------x--------------x--------------x-
```

Where each character width in the diagram is 40 seconds of time and `x` represent shift changing.

solution is then 10mins divided by 40secs = 15 drills

---

EDIT: Let me just guess the details and answer the question in case each site have a differing walking time to and from the base.

In that case, I just split the `x` mark in the diagram into 2 halves `>`, `<` corresponding to a guy going out and in respectively. Additionally have `w` represent the fixed round trip time for each drill.

It is also clear which drill we are talking about, always pick the closest drills first.

The diagram becomes (not to scale):

```
drill-1  >w<-------------->w<-------------->w<-------------->w<
drill-2  ->ww<------------->ww<------------->ww<------------->w
drill-3  -->ww<------------->ww<------------->ww<------------->
drill-3  --->www<------------>www<------------>www<------------
...
```

Where the constraint is that no `>` or `<` marks can overlap.

However, you can just think of the allocation in the in a single 10-minutes slice.
Since the diagram will always have a repeating period of 10 minutes.

Why? because if any of the drill chart has repeating period of more than 10 minutes some astronaut will die.
And if any of the drill has repeating period of less than 10 minutes, you can just let the astronaut go sightseeing so to extend the period back to 10. That is, if you don't any better allocation to do.

At this point you could probably write a brute force to try to allocate those markings in just that limited time period.

---

EDIT2: I think there might be a flaw in my reasoning why consindering only 10 minutes period is enough.

Comment: In the simplest form where all drill sites are equal distant from the base it will work as you suggest.  How do you solve the problem if all the drill sites are different distances?

Comment: Well, then you better describe in the question how the distance effect the time it takes to get mining!

Comment: And I don't mean describe it as "...walks to the worksite, works, walks back to base..." like you already did. I mean, describe what information do you have that helps calculate the time to walk to each site? do you have astronaut walking speed? do you have a map of the whole mining area? do all site have equal distance to the base? do all astronaut walk at the same speed? Also, do astronaut have to walk through a maze of asteroid field and fight aliens before mining? ;P

Comment: @user3799626 Sorry I believe my advanced case answer still contain a flaw. But don't have anymore time to spend on this.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It is a little hard to explain but basically it takes more workers for farther away points. The return-home times get out of sync after time and the airlock could block someone out.